# Hadoop streaming --- expensive shared resource (COOL)

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I am looking for a nice pattern for python hadoop streaming that involves loading an expensive resource, for example a pickled python object on the server. Here is what I came up with; I've tested by piping input files and slow running programs directly into the script in bash, but haven't yet run it on a hadoop cluster. For you hadoop wizards---am i handling io such that this will work as a python streaming job? I guess I'll go spin up something on amazon to test but it would be nice if someone knew off the top.

you can test it out via `cat file.txt | the_script` or `./a_streaming_program | the_script`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time

def resources_for_many_lines():
  # load slow, shared resources here
  # for example, a shared pickle file

  # in this example we use a 1 second sleep to simulate
  # a long data load
  time.sleep(1)

  # we will pretend the value zero is the product
  # of our long slow running import
  resource = 0

  return resource

def score_a_line(line, resources):
  # put fast code to score a single example line here
  # in this example we will return the value of resource + 1
  return resources + 1

def run():
  # here is the code that reads stdin and scores the model over a streaming data set
  resources = resources_for_many_lines()
  while 1:
    # reads a line of input
    line = sys.stdin.readline()

    # ends if pipe closes
    if line == '':
      break

    # scores a line
    print score_a_line(line, resources)
    # prints right away instead of waiting
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  run();
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine to me. I often load up yaml or sqlite resources in my mappers.

You typically won't be running *that* many mappers in your job so even if you spend a couple of seconds in loading something from disk it's usually not a huge problem.